# displaying values from mysqli with php

Tags: php, mysqli

Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/husbQ7hc

On line 33 it has:

```
echo $value;
```

How can I have it that I can use it like below:

```
echo $value['module_name'];
echo $value['module_name_id'];
echo $value['module_image'];
```

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: Place your pertinent code in your question as well.

Comment: Do a `var_dump` of `$final`

Comment: I placed the var_dump($final); on line 20. This is the output http://pastebin.com/Mw9vtRTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During your final result fetch on line 13:

```
// Retrieve results
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Add to final array via counter if valid course is found
    if (in_array($row['course_name'], $courses)) {
            $final[$row['course_name']][] = $row['module_name'];
    }
}
```

Rather than storing just the column value of `$row['module_name']`, store the entire row to access it later:

```
$final[$row['course_name']][] = $row;
```

Then when you "loop through the internal values" on line 32 you can access any column you want using:

```
echo $value['module_name'];
echo $value['module_name_id'];
echo $value['module_image'];
```

Comment: How can I get it to display the course description after the course name on line 29. course_desc is in the Table courses.

Comment: sorry your link is no longer valid so i can't see your code. However, if it is a value from another table that you are after then I would suggest you do a [SQL JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) in you main query so you can access those values later in your `$final` array. If this isn't correct then paste your code in your question and I'll look at it.